# Network manager connection editor can't start

Tags: network-manager

I'm having trouble starting the connection editor. I can't start it from the GUI, so I tried entering `nm-connection-editor` at a terminal, but got this error. Anyone know what it means? I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and haven't found any solutions for this error so far. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling network manager, but I get the same error.

```
nm-connection-editor: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/NetworkManager/libnm-viavpn-properties.so: undefined symbol: LOG_init
```

Comment: I'm on 14.04 LTS and I don't have that `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/libnm-viavpn-properties.so:`  file , but then again - i am not using vpn, so perhaps that's the error.

Comment: Possibly relevant? https://support.csuchico.edu/TDClient/KB/ArticleDet?ID=7601

Comment: I don't have clearpass onguard on this install. I'm not using a vpn either so I don't know what's causing this error at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It may not be the best solution, but I can now start the connection editor. After uninstalling network manager I deleted the `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/` directory and its contents. Afterwards I reinstalled `network-manager` and `network-manager-gnome` and can now start the connection editor using the GUI and `nm-connection-editor` at the terminal.