# Wi-Fi only loads websites and nothing elese

Tags: networking, internet

I have been using a recently installed xUbuntu HP laptop (2019 originally windows laptop) and recently, the internet has stopped working all of the sudden. I can connect to networks just fine, but when I do connect, I can only load websites on my browser. In fact, I am writing this on my computer now. Pinging a website fails, playing games fails, streaming music fails. The thing is that all of my other devices at my house connected on the same network can use the internet just fine so idk what happened to my compter.

I have tried editing my DNS to google's and OpenDNS's servers. I followed many guides from this website such as `sudo iptables -F` and `sudo dhclient -r` and none of them have worked. I also followed the network troubleshooting guide on the xUbuntu website. I usually am good at fixing errors to do with the internet but this one has stumped me. Any advice is appreciated.

EDIT:
Here is some things that I tried: 
[No internet access in certain apps randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895750/no-internet-access-in-certain-apps-randomly) 
https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-reset-the-network-settings-to-default-ubuntu-16/ 
[https://devconnected.com/how-to-flush-dns-cache-on-linux/#:~:text=The%20easiest%20way%20to%20flush,%E2%80%9Cflush%2Dcaches%E2%80%9D%20option](https://devconnected.com/how-to-flush-dns-cache-on-linux/#:%7E:text=The%20easiest%20way%20to%20flush,%E2%80%9Cflush%2Dcaches%E2%80%9D%20option) (tried the Flush "DNS using systemd-resolved" Section) 
[How do I completely reset network settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176351/how-do-i-completely-reset-network-settings) (tried the top voted answer here) 
https://docs.xubuntu.org/current/user/C/internet-networks.html (Did all network troubleshooting links)

Also, I did `arp -a` and it can only see my router and my computer. I tried pinging another computer on the network and it didn't ping it so just weird things all around.

EDIT2:
Did `arp -a` again and now it lists 3 devices. My computer, the router, and some other device that has a average ping of 1.252ms

UPDATE:
As seen the correspondence below, plugging a Ethernet cable into my computer did work when pinging websites. This still doesn't fix the issue but is good info.

Comment: Does it work ok if you plug a blue ethernet cable between your computer and the router?

Comment: Are you sure your WiFi or Network Router is not setup to block certain ports or addresses? Do you have a specific DNS server configured on your WiFi or Network Router?

Comment: @PJSingh My father set up OpenDNS on our internet to block inappropriate websites but that has not caused me trouble for a few years. Besides, I have been able to do stuff on linux before this point. In the links I provided I tried switching my DNS settings in my computer to Google's (Which has helped me on windows before) but to my disappointment that did not solve the issue on my linux computer.

Comment: And as for @WinEunuuchs2Unix 's Question I will try that tonight

Comment: It might be OpenDNS that is causing your issue. I don't think bypassing it by changing the local machines DNS setting works anymore.

Comment: @PJSingh I know that. It was not to bypass the restrictions. The DNS on another device a while back needed to use the google DNS for it to work. That is all that I meant. WinEunuuchs2Unix made a good suggestion so I'm going to try that now.

Comment: Alright, plugging into the router works with no errors. Pinging  any website works. I believe OpenDNS still applies even when I'm wired. (don't want to go to a naughty site to test that theory ) I don't think it is OpenDNS unless it has something to do with blocking only wireless connections. If you all believe it is necessary, I could ask my father to check the settings of the router and OpenDNS but they haven't changed in over 4 years so I'm not sure that is the issue.

Comment: I see you've solved your problem. As an FYI, OpenDNS does have safe testing URLs that you can use to verify functionality without attempting unsafe URLs: https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/227986567-How-to-Test-for-Successful-OpenDNS-Configuration-

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was very strange but I am answering my own question. (Feel free to reply and give your theory as to why this happened if you would like just in case this happens to me again)

So I was very frustrated because I was using my Phone's hotspot to connect to my school and so I kept looking for answers on this website. I also had this issue which was frustrating [Why is the Edit button greyed out in Network Manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79546/why-is-the-edit-button-greyed-out-in-network-manager) 
but the internet issue was more important (i could still edit connections in the settings menu at the time) 
So the top voted answer in that link was "Run in terminal sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart"
On xUbuntu this is called network-manager not networking but anyways. What I did instead of `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart` is `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager status`
This told me every thing it was doing when connecting to a network. It said it was still connected to my phone so I switched to my home wifi. I ran the command again and the last thing it said was `manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL` and I tried pinging google.com and my personal website and it replied. I opened a game as well just to make sure and it booted up just fine with online connectivity. I have no idea why checking the status fixed it but it did. I didn't do anything else other than connect to my phone and then back to the home wifi and type in that command. I had done the connecting back and forth between the phone and my home network for a few days now so idk what the heck the command did but it fixed it.

EDIT:
It is broken again and this answer DOESNT fix it so this proboly didnt fix it the first time